# What's clobbering window.page on my Galaxy S3?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Do some browsers use `window.page` for something?

I ask because my web app mysteriously failed on my Galaxy S3 phone running Android 4.3.  Investigation revealed that something had clobbered my global variable `page` with an `HTMLBodyElement`.  It works just fine in my Android 4.3 virtual machine.  Here's a POC:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.page = 0;
      window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
      function start()
      {
          if (isNaN(window.page))
              alert(window.page);
          setTimeout(function(){alert(window.page);}, 5000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>This is some text that is long enough to wrap around.</td>
        <td>This is some text that is long enough to wrap around.</td>
        <td>This is some text that is long enough to wrap around.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected behaviour: a message box in 5 seconds saying `0` (the value assigned to window.page).

Observed behaviour: a message box in 5 seconds saying 
`[object HTMLBodyElement]`

It only seems to reproduce under some very specific circumstances; for instance, if the text in the table cells doesn't wrap around, `window.page` stays as `0`.  And as I said, I've only seen this occur on my Samsung Galaxy S3; I've observed no problems on my Android 4.2 tablet or Firefox, Chrome, or IE on my desktop.

I can work around this by simply renaming `page`.  But I'd like to know what's going on here and if any of my other globals are going to get stomped on.

Comment: Just a general suggestion: Avoid all global variables in the first place. This will prevent any side effects with collisions with third party scripts and browser specific global variables.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. It looks like it happens during a setInterval or onResize

Comment: @RoToRa you do need at least one global variable right? To use as a namespace for all your other stuff. Well, I used 'page' as my root variable :)

Comment: @DirkBoer You should at least use a variable name that is less generic, e.g. `dirkBoerPage`. In the case of the original question no global variables are needed at all - and I would allege, that it's possible to write JavaScript without using any global variables.

Answer (score 1):

As RoToRa pointed out in the comment, there may be browser specific global variables or addons that interfere with your script. It's best to avoid using them. However, if you want to see what's happening specifically in your phone's browser, use this to list out 'window' object's keys:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    keyList = Object.keys(window);
    for(var i in keyList) { 
        document.write(keyList [i]+"<br>"); 
    }
</script>
```